# Convert nested spark Row to nested map Map[String, Any] (and visa versa)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Want functions

`row` is assumed to be a nested structure.  The output map keys should be the full paths of the field keys (/column names).  E.g. if the input structure is `{foo: { bar: 1}, bob: "alice"}` then the output map should be `Map("foo" -> Map("foo.bar" -> 1))`

```
def rowToMap(row: Row): Map[String, Any]
```

Hoping there is a neat way to do this, if not will likely have to use recursion on `row.schema`.

Similarly given a nested map, e.g. `Map("foo" -> Map("bar" -> 1), "bob" -> "alice")` (note we don't need to parse full path).

```
def mapToRow(map: Map[String, Any]): Row
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
object RDDOfMapToDataFrame {
  def apply(rdd: RDD[Map[String, Any]], schema: StructType)
           (implicit sparkSession: SparkSession): DataFrame =
    sparkSession.createDataFrame(rdd.map(mapToRow(_, schema.structType)), schema)

  def getStructTypeFromStructType(field: String, schema: StructType): StructType =
    schema.fields(schema.fieldIndex(field)).dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]

  def getStructTypeFromArrayType(field: String, schema: StructType): StructType =
    schema.fields(schema.fieldIndex(field)).dataType.asInstanceOf[ArrayType].elementType.asInstanceOf[StructType]

  def mapToRow(m: Map[String, Any], schema: StructType): Row = Row.fromSeq(m.toList.map {
    case (key, struct: Map[String, Any]@unchecked) =>
      schema.fieldIndex(key) -> mapToRow(struct, getStructTypeFromStructType(key, schema))
    // Intellij is confused by this line, please leave as is
    case (key, mapList) if mapList.isInstanceOf[TraversableOnce[_]]
      && mapList.asInstanceOf[TraversableOnce[Any]].toSeq.headOption.exists(_.isInstanceOf[Map[_, _]]) =>
      schema.fieldIndex(key) ->
        mapList.asInstanceOf[TraversableOnce[Any]]
          .toSeq
          .map(_.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]])
          .map(mapToRow(_, getStructTypeFromArrayType(key, schema)))
    case (key, None) =>
      schema.fieldIndex(key) -> null
    case (key, Some(other: Map[_, _])) =>
      schema.fieldIndex(key) -> mapToRow(other.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]], getStructTypeFromStructType(key, schema))
    case (key, Some(mapList))
      if mapList.isInstanceOf[TraversableOnce[_]]
        && mapList.asInstanceOf[TraversableOnce[Any]].toSeq.headOption.exists(_.isInstanceOf[Map[_, _]]) =>
      schema.fieldIndex(key) ->
        mapList.asInstanceOf[TraversableOnce[Any]]
          .toSeq
          .map(_.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]])
          .map(mapToRow(_, getStructTypeFromArrayType(key, schema)))
    case x@(key, Some(other)) =>
      schema.fieldIndex(key) -> other
    case (key, other) =>
      schema.fieldIndex(key) -> other
  }.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2))

  def rowToMap(row: Row): Map[String, Any] = row.schema.fieldNames.zip(row.toSeq.map {
    case row: Row => rowToMap(row)
    // Intellij is confused by this line, please leave as is
    case seqOfRow@((_: Row) :: _) => seqOfRow.map(_.asInstanceOf[Row]).map(rowToMap)
    case any => any
  }).toMap
}
```

Comment: the code is quite complex to be sure of the results. Could you give some example with input and output?